# Unit test for component in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

hi i am new to react testing and i am using react testing library and jest.please help me in writing test case for below code.

```
  import React from 'react'

import {
  Loader,
  SectionTitle,
  ErrorLabel,
} from 'LookingGlass/common/components'

import LookingGlassPanelResultSection from 'LookingGlass/app/components/LookingGlassResultSection'

import constants from 'LookingGlass/constants'

import getErrorMessage from 'LookingGlass/app/utils/getErrorMessage'
import styles from './_.index.module.scss'

export default function LookingGlassPanelResults(props) {
  const { queryResult, isTimedOut, error, isServerDown, isLoading } = props

  if (isLoading)
    return (
      <Loader
        content={constants.Loader.loaderContent}
        active
        inline="centered"
        size="large"
      />
    )

  if (isServerDown) {
    return <ErrorLabel text={constants.error.message.error_404} />
  }

  if (isTimedOut) {
    return <ErrorLabel text={constants.requestsTimeout.msg} />
  }

  if (error) {
    return <ErrorLabel text={getErrorMessage(error)} />
  }

  if (!queryResult) return null

  return (
    <div>
      <hr className={styles.seperateLine} />
      <SectionTitle text={constants.QueryPanelResult.resultPanel} />
      <LookingGlassPanelResultSection queryResult={queryResult} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

ErrorLabel is different component where icon is used and text is displayed. How to write test where we use component inside component ?

this is my test case:-

```
 const renderComponent = (props) =>
    render(<LookingGlassPanelResults {...props} />)
    test('Verify that isServerDown  parameter works', () => {
        const component = renderComponent({ isServerDown: true })
        const { getByText } = within(component)
        expect(
          getByText('Service unavailable. Please try later'),
        ).toBeInTheDocument()
      })
```

Error:-`

```
TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got Object.

      20 |     const { getByText } = within(component)
      21 |     expect(
    > 22 |       getByText('Service unavailable. Please try later'),
         |       ^
      23 |     ).toBeInTheDocument()
      24 |   })`
```

Comment: It's the same process as a writing test for a single component: provide required props and write expectations you want to test. Have you tried to do something on your own?

Comment: yes when i did the same you told, there is an error

Comment: But we don't know what the error is.

Comment: i have udpdated my question. i am actually not sure whether my test is right or wrong so i didnt posted it first .

Comment: What is renderComponent? Please, add a screenshot in addition to error because it's unclear which line it refers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here first we need to get ErrorLabel by test-id and then check expectations

```
test('Verify that isServerDown  parameter works', () => {
    const component = renderComponent({ isServerDown: true })
    const { getByTestId } = component

    expect(getByTestId('ErrorLabel')).toHaveTextContent(
      'Service unavailable. Please try later',
    )
  })
```